# Send Decipher / Cipher Object (binary data) with request() to API with multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

We have two API's in Node.js. The first one acts as the main hub, while the other one is used to send emails.

Currently I have some files that are encrypted and stored in the file system of the first API. The files get decrypted with the following function:

```
decryptFile: function (filePath, callback) {
                var fileName = path.basename(filePath);
                var encryptedFilePath = path.dirname(filePath) + '/' + this.encryptText(fileName);
                // input file
                var fileDecipher = encryptionKeys.crypto.createDecipher(encryptionKeys.algorithm, encryptionKeys.password);
                var r = fs.createReadStream(encryptedFilePath);
                // decrypt content
                r.on("error", function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        callback(err);
                    }
                });
                return callback(null, r.pipe(fileDecipher));

        }
```

To send the files we use:

```
utils.files.decryptFile(fullPath, function (err, decryptedFile) {

requestOptions = {
            url: pushAPIURL + 'email/send',
            method: "POST",
            formData: {
               attachments: [decryptedFile]
            },
            headers: {
                authorization: global.PUSHToken
            }
            // json: body
        };
        return request(requestOptions);
});
```

Due to this we receive:

> Error: Part terminated early due to unexpected end of multipart data

on the mail API

Any idea as to what may be missing from the request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after some digging, I had forgotten about the question over here. I posted the solution to my problem inside form-data's GitHub issue's: https://github.com/form-data/form-data/issues/409#issuecomment-432202588

Here is the original answer in case the above is not available anymore:

> So the solution to this was thanks to:
>   https://github.com/form-data/form-data/issues/356#issue-234978025
>
> It seems indeed related to the missing known length of the stream +
>   seemingly some other metadata fields that are missing. On the file
>   decryption function, I added the counting of the stream length for
>   each chunk:
>
> ```
>             let file, length = 0;
>             // decrypt content
>             r.on("error", function (err) {
>                 if (err) {
>                     callback(err);
>                 }
>             });
>             r.on("data", function (chunk) {
>                 // console.log("data");
>                 length += chunk.length;
>             });
>             r.on("end", function () {
>                 // console.log("end");
>                 return callback(null, file, fileName, length);
>             });
>             file = r.pipe(fileDecipher);
> ```
>
> Then, on the file that is sending the request we add the following
>
> ```
> utils.files.decryptFile(fullPath, function (err, decryptedFile, filename, >length) {
>             decryptedFile.httpVersion = "1.0";
>             decryptedFile.name = filename;
>             decryptedFile.headers = {'content-length': length};
>             requestOptions = {
>             url: pushAPIURL + 'email/send',
>             method: "POST",
>             formData: {
>                attachments: [decryptedFile]
>             },
>             headers: {
>                 authorization: global.PUSHToken
>             }
>         };
>         return request(requestOptions); 
>     });
> ```